# Make Super Fine Sugar

Tags: equipment, sugar

I am looking into creating some super fine sugar (finer than confectioners sugar) for icing. This is more for experimentation than anything, I am more interested to see how this impacts the consistency/texture of the icing than anything. I've tried using a blender and a coffee grinder, starting with both granulated and confectioners sugar, but can't seem to get much finer than the confectioners sugar.

I'm willing to build a device, but I'm not sure the best path forward here. My thoughts were something along the lines of an old stone mill, except in this case I would use food grade steel plates, but that is a big investment.

Is there something existing I can re-purpose for this endeavor or perhaps something relatively low cost I can buy? If not, thoughts on my plan above?

Comment: There are food-grade modern electrical stone mills, mostly to be found on the indian market as "wet grinders" ... But I doubt they would get sugar very fine, the pressure is more likely to "sinter" than further grind the sugar after a point...

Comment: If you can obtain some sufficiently fine sieves, you can use any method by sieving out the sufficiently fine stuff and regrinding the rest. Keeping the sugar really, really dry (or even baking it dry) could also help. Careful with super-fine sugar, btw ... keep the dust from ignition sources :)

Comment: @rackandboneman yeah, I remember reading about the one in Georgia about a decade back. Definitely don't want a repeat in my kitchen. Thanks for the tip on the stone mill and sintering. I'll keep that in mind, I would imagine dryness is the key at that point.

Comment: My blender allows me to make powder sugar from cane sugar, but it gets lumpy rather quickly even when kept in vacuum-sealed jars, so I have to make it and use it immediately.  What kind of blender do you use? (Mine's a Kenwood)

Comment: I'm using a magic bullet and noticed it does start to clump after a while. I suspect that is due to heat as the sugar is quite hot after a short time. You can combat the clumping in the jar with corn starch.